# Using placeholder in RewriteCond to be applied to RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using a placeholder in the `RewriteCond` which I expected to populate `$1`, and a second placeholder in the `RewriteRule` which I expected to populate `$2`.

It appears, however, that `$1` is the placeholder set by the `RewriteRule`, and `$2` is empty.

How can a placeholder be defined in the `RewriteCond` and applied to the `RewriteRule`?

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).sites.example.com [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^public/(.+)$ public/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

rewrite log:

```
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> public/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] RewriteCond: input='test.sites.example.com' pattern='^(.+).sites.example.com' [NC] => matched
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html' -> 'public/xxx.html/'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add per-dir prefix: public/xxx.html/ -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/ -> public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (4) add subst prefix: public/xxx.html/ -> /public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/xxx.html/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4547b8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4547b8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/ -> public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4547b8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html/'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4547b8/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] RewriteCond: input='test.sites.example.com' pattern='^(.+).sites.example.com' [NC] => matched
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4547b8/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html/' -> 'public/xxx.html//'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4547b8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add per-dir prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4547b8/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4547b8/initial/redir#1] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html// -> public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4547b8/initial/redir#1] (4) add subst prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4547b8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/xxx.html// [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b459968/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b459968/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/ -> public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b459968/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html/'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b459968/initial/redir#2] (4) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] RewriteCond: input='test.sites.example.com' pattern='^(.+).sites.example.com' [NC] => matched
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b459968/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html/' -> 'public/xxx.html//'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b459968/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add per-dir prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b459968/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b459968/initial/redir#2] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html// -> public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b459968/initial/redir#2] (4) add subst prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b459968/initial/redir#2] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/xxx.html// [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b45eb88/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b45eb88/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/ -> public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b45eb88/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html/'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b45eb88/initial/redir#3] (4) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] RewriteCond: input='test.sites.example.com' pattern='^(.+).sites.example.com' [NC] => matched
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b45eb88/initial/redir#3] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html/' -> 'public/xxx.html//'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b45eb88/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add per-dir prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b45eb88/initial/redir#3] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b45eb88/initial/redir#3] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html// -> public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b45eb88/initial/redir#3] (4) add subst prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b45eb88/initial/redir#3] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/xxx.html// [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b463dd0/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b463dd0/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/ -> public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b463dd0/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html/'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b463dd0/initial/redir#4] (4) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] RewriteCond: input='test.sites.example.com' pattern='^(.+).sites.example.com' [NC] => matched
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b463dd0/initial/redir#4] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html/' -> 'public/xxx.html//'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b463dd0/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add per-dir prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b463dd0/initial/redir#4] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b463dd0/initial/redir#4] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html// -> public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b463dd0/initial/redir#4] (4) add subst prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b463dd0/initial/redir#4] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/xxx.html// [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b469218/initial/redir#5] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b469218/initial/redir#5] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/ -> public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b469218/initial/redir#5] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html/'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b469218/initial/redir#5] (4) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] RewriteCond: input='test.sites.example.com' pattern='^(.+).sites.example.com' [NC] => matched
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b469218/initial/redir#5] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html/' -> 'public/xxx.html//'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b469218/initial/redir#5] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add per-dir prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b469218/initial/redir#5] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b469218/initial/redir#5] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html// -> public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b469218/initial/redir#5] (4) add subst prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b469218/initial/redir#5] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/xxx.html// [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b46e628/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b46e628/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/ -> public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b46e628/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html/'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b46e628/initial/redir#6] (4) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] RewriteCond: input='test.sites.example.com' pattern='^(.+).sites.example.com' [NC] => matched
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b46e628/initial/redir#6] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html/' -> 'public/xxx.html//'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b46e628/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add per-dir prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b46e628/initial/redir#6] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b46e628/initial/redir#6] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html// -> public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b46e628/initial/redir#6] (4) add subst prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b46e628/initial/redir#6] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/xxx.html// [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b473d88/initial/redir#7] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b473d88/initial/redir#7] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/ -> public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b473d88/initial/redir#7] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html/'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b473d88/initial/redir#7] (4) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] RewriteCond: input='test.sites.example.com' pattern='^(.+).sites.example.com' [NC] => matched
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b473d88/initial/redir#7] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html/' -> 'public/xxx.html//'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b473d88/initial/redir#7] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add per-dir prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b473d88/initial/redir#7] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b473d88/initial/redir#7] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html// -> public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b473d88/initial/redir#7] (4) add subst prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b473d88/initial/redir#7] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/xxx.html// [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4792d8/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4792d8/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/ -> public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4792d8/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html/'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4792d8/initial/redir#8] (4) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] RewriteCond: input='test.sites.example.com' pattern='^(.+).sites.example.com' [NC] => matched
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4792d8/initial/redir#8] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html/' -> 'public/xxx.html//'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4792d8/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add per-dir prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4792d8/initial/redir#8] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4792d8/initial/redir#8] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html// -> public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4792d8/initial/redir#8] (4) add subst prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b4792d8/initial/redir#8] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/xxx.html// [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b47f498/initial/redir#9] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b47f498/initial/redir#9] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/ -> public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b47f498/initial/redir#9] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html/'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b47f498/initial/redir#9] (4) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] RewriteCond: input='test.sites.example.com' pattern='^(.+).sites.example.com' [NC] => matched
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b47f498/initial/redir#9] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html/' -> 'public/xxx.html//'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b47f498/initial/redir#9] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add per-dir prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b47f498/initial/redir#9] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b47f498/initial/redir#9] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html// -> public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b47f498/initial/redir#9] (4) add subst prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b47f498/initial/redir#9] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/xxx.html// [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b484cb8/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b484cb8/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html/ -> public/xxx.html/
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b484cb8/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html/'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b484cb8/initial/redir#10] (4) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] RewriteCond: input='test.sites.example.com' pattern='^(.+).sites.example.com' [NC] => matched
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b484cb8/initial/redir#10] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html/' -> 'public/xxx.html//'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b484cb8/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add per-dir prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b484cb8/initial/redir#10] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b484cb8/initial/redir#10] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html// -> public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b484cb8/initial/redir#10] (4) add subst prefix: public/xxx.html// -> /public/xxx.html//
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b484cb8/initial/redir#10] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/xxx.html// [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+)$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f4a2b120f18][rid#7f4a2b43cbf8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] pass through /var/www/mysite/html_sites/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placeholders for RewriteCond use `%` and placeholders for RewriteRule use `$`.  Change to...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).sites.example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^public/(.+)$ public/%1/$1 [NC,L]
```